# how can i access terminal in visual studio code which is not working?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]I opened terminal in vs code but the path is not coming. On clicking the terminal also the text is not appearing which I am typing. I am not able to type anything in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the View menu of VScode. Then click on the menu option "Integrated Terminal". This will open the terminal window at bottom of VScode window.